# Maxcript : search a specific object in my selection, by name

Tags: python, object, search, selection, maxscript

I want to search a specific object by name in my selection.

For example: in 3ds max I select 2 objects.

in `Selection` search for the object named `"BOX"` and rename it to `"test"`
for now I can only filter with [1] & [2]. What I want would be more ["BOX"] but it doesn't work.

```
on button1 pressed do with undo on
(
    object1 = selection[1]
    object2 = selection[2]
    if selection.count == 2 and Superclassof object1 == Geometryclass and Superclassof object2 == Geometryclass then 

            for i in selection do
            (
                object1.name = "test"
                object2.name = "test2"
                freeze object2
            ) 
    else
            messagebox ("!") title:"ERROR:"
        )
```

Thanks to swordslayer I manage to do this:

```
on button pressed do with undo on
(
    if selection.count == 2 and Superclassof obj1 == Geometryclass and Superclassof obj2 == Geometryclass then
        (
                    for obj1 in selection where obj1.name == "BOX" do
                        (obj1.name = "test")
                    for obj2 in selection where obj2.name == "_high" do
                        (obj.name = "test2")
                )
    else
            messagebox ("!") title:"ERROR:"
        )
```

unfortunatly restriction Superclassof is not working anymore !

Answer (score 1):

As usual, depending on how you wanna acutally use it, there're many ways to do that, for example

```
for obj in selection where obj.name == "BOX" do obj.name = "test"
```

or

```
for obj in getNodeByName "BOX" ignoreCase:on all:on where obj.isSelected do obj.name = "test"
```

or even

```
$selection/*Box.name = "test"
```

Edit: if you really only have two objects selected:

```
if selection.count == 2 do case of
(
    (selection[1].name as name == #box) : selection[1].name = uniqueName selection[2].name
    (selection[2].name as name == #box) : selection[2].name = uniqueName selection[1].name
    default: messageBox "Error"
)
```

Comment: thanks Swordslayer ! it's working but my superclassof do not work anymore

Comment: Well, the rest of the code would be a different question altogether... That's why I said it really depends on what you actually want to do.

Comment: In the code :<br>for obj in selection where obj.name == "BOX" do obj.name = "test". how can I replace "test" to get the name of object2 ?

Comment: See the edit, I though your example was just an example.